# Why does my newborn stick her tongue in and out like a snake?

Tags: newborn

Like a snake in the attack mood sticks his tongue in and out repeatedly, the same way my newborn sticks her tongue in and out repeatedly - nearly the whole day.

What does this indicate?

Comment: Sometimes a childhood frined of mine would stick out their tongue until it dried. "Funny sensation",  they said.

Answer (score 6):

New sensation to be explored?  Hoping there's some food out there?  Kids do weird things.  If you are truly concerned, ask your pediatrician, but my guess is it's something new she learned how to do and now she's practicing her new skill.  Soon it'll be something else; they gain so many skills and experiences in these days that it's dizzying to try to keep up.

Answer (score 3):

My kids would do this when they were hungry.